# Glob on a remote machine

Tags: perl, glob

Is there a way to get a glob from a remote machine? I'm thinking of something like this:

```
my @arr = glob('$IP_ADRESS:/usr/local/*');
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find anything useful yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try ssh http://search.cpan.org/~schwigon/Net-SSH-Perl-1.36/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm which works at a higher level as you need to negotiate the permissions on the remote machine

```
 use Net::SSH::Perl;
 my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
 $ssh->login($user, $pass);
 my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Net::SFTP::Foreign provides a `glob` method.

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host);
my @files = $sftp->glob('/usr/local/*', names_only => 1);
```